# How to find a list of jobs with no workers

Tags: python, celery

When using Celery you can use `i.inspect()` to find the active tasks, the tasks that have been scheduled and all the registered tasks. However, I have disabled pre-fetch, so only 1 job is registered to a worker at a time. How do I access a list of all jobs in the queue, that do not have a registered worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use RabbitMQ, [read this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=list%20tasks#rabbitmq). If you use Redis [read this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=list%20tasks#redis). It gives an information how many tasks there are in particular queue.

Since I believe you want to list all the tasks waiting in the queue, you need to iterate through the list. If you use Redis for an example, instead of `llen` like in the example in the documentation, you would iterate through the QUEUE_NAME list (it is a Redis list object). NOTE: This process can take some time so by the time you go through the list some of the tasks may already be finished.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I can do this directly from inside python though, rather than having to make a redis-cli system call?

Comment: Sure there is - use the same library Celery uses to communicate with Redis - [redis-py](https://pypi.org/project/redis/)